# How do I create an array of numbers?

Tags: arrays, liquid

I've been struggling with this now for about three hours. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to create/use an array of numbers in the Liquid templating language. Infuriatingly, the [docs](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/types/) tell me that I should be able to, but provide no examples as to how, and I can't find any on the internet either.
The only thing I'm able to create is an array of strings, like so:

```
{% assign my_list = "A, B, C" | split ", " %}
```

It must be something simple that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to init an array you need to use a string.
However, all you have to do to turn array elem into integer is to use a math filter.

For example, to output integers without modifying their values, you might write:

```
{%  assign numbers = '1,2,3' | split:',' %}
{%  for number in numbers %}
    {{ number | plus:0 }}
{%  endfor %}
```

This will output 1 2 3 as numbers.

If you want to modify values, you might write:

```
{%  assign numbers = '1,2,3' | split:',' %}
{%  for number in numbers %}
    {{ number | plus:number }}
{%  endfor %}
```

This will output 2 4 6 as numbers.

HTH